# MediaElement XAML -> AutoPlay not a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I have created a MediaElement in XAML and assigned a .mpg as the source.

Looking at the XAML controls gallery from Microsoft, there are some examples such as:

```
<MediaPlayerElement Source="Assets/SampleMedia/fishes.wmv"
                    MaxWidth="400"
                    AutoPlay="True" />
```

However, I am faced with invalid markup that is returning: 
*The property AutoPlay was not found in type `MediaElement`*

I have tried removing the AutoPlay and using a MediaOpened event to start the video from code behind,but there is never any trigger even?

I am not having too much success.

DO I need to add any additional resources to access certain properties?

```
        <MediaElement x:Name="backdropMotion" Source="Images/inMotion_video.mpg" 
                      Stretch="Fill" Margin="198,126,-326,229" Grid.Column="2"                      
                      LoadedBehavior="Play" IsEnabled="True" IsMuted="True" 
                      Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MediaOpened="MediaOpenedEvent"
                      AutoPlay="True"
                      >
```

Ultimately, I am trying to run a media element to a panel that effectively acts as an animated background, looping almost like a .gif. First step is to get the element running.

Comment: MediaElement and MediaPlayerElement are different classes in different frameworks. `LoadedBehavior="Play"` should be all you need, but is the default anyway.

Comment: OK, I can see I have copied from the wrong XAML COntrolls Gallery. However, the MediaELement also uses the same AutoPlay:

Comment: ````<MediaElement Source="/Assets/SampleMedia/ladybug.wmv"
              MaxWidth="400"
              AutoPlay="False"
              AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />````

Comment: That also seems to be UWP, not WPF.

Comment: OK. I think my research has been confused between UWP and WPF, thanks for the heads-up. I have realised the element was not playing as the "Copy to Ouput Directory" of the resource was not set to "Copy always". Thanks.